# PC is grappled. Is there chance another PC (in melee combat) will hit him instead of the grappling enemy?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, combat, grapple

The PC is grappled by a creature (here a chuul). Another player is in melee combat. Does the PC have to roll anything to determine if he hits the PC or chuul?

Comment: Yes, I meant melee combat.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### No, there is no chance to hit the wrong target with a melee attack.

According to the [Table: Armor Class Modifiers](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/combatModifiers.htm), if defender is grappling but attacker is not, the defender loses any Dexterity bonus to AC against ranged and melee attacks from the attacker. But "Roll randomly to see which grappling combatant you strike" footnote applies to ranged attacks only.

---

For the sake of compliteness, if you are making ranged attack into a grapple through, aforementioned footnote applies. You should devide 100 by the number of creatures involved in grapple and tell to the GM wich of resulting parts represents each. Then roll d100.
You, of course, may just roll d2 for two creatures, d3 for 3 creatures and so on. It is technically the same.

Comment: for the sake of completeness. a ranged attack?